# Ошибка argument type is not assignable C# из-за смены пространства имён

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, я передаю аргумент и он имеет пространство имён UI.Font в новой библиотеке которую я использую.

В старой библиотеке не было этого пространства имён, был тупо класс Font.

Сам класс Font одинаковый полностью, как мне успокоить компилятор?
Учитывая что я не имею доступ к библиотеке (к коду и подправить не могу), который строго показывает мне использовать GTA.UI, вместо GTA.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже «полностью одинаковые» классы, лежащие в разных пространствах имён, считаются разными — C# всё же строго типизированный язык.

Если у вас поменялась одна из библиотек с потерей обратной совместимости, вам придётся обновить и остальные библиотеки на совместимые версии. «Заткнуть» компилятор невозможно, да и неправильно.